# What is wrong with my Angular-EL expression in Websphere?

Tags: websphere

I use a completely-server-side i18n mechanism for my Java web application.

We created an EL wrapper for `java.text.MessageFormat.format` function that takes as inputs a localized pattern and parameters.

I need to display text that changes with user language (server side) and Angular variable value.

Consider the following example

- EN: "Hello, {0}"
- IT: "Ciao, {0}"

Now `{{vmApp.principal}}` is `'Bobby'`

An expression of the following type does not work in Websphere

```
${acme:messageFormat1(messages.GREETING,'{{vmApp.principal}}'}
```

And the error is....

```
[22/03/18 16.14.22:169 CET] 000000bc webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/secure/admin/pages/process/detail.jsp]: com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslationException: JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /secure/admin/pages/process/detail.jsp:  
/secure/admin/pages/process/detail.jsp(8,9) --> JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function ${pnx:messageFormat1(messages.PROCESS_DETAIL_EXECUTION_STARTCTX,'{{vmApp.row.exceptionClass}.

                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ELValidator.validateElFunction(ELValidator.java:505)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ELValidator.validateELExpression(ELValidator.java:123)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.visitJspELTextStart(ValidateVisitor.java:1268)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.visitCDataTag(ValidateVisitor.java:887)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:409)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:369)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:369)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:369)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:234)
                at com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.visit(JspVisitor.java:216)
```

My research guided me to [this article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21642419) by IBM but I don't think it applies to my case because the stack trace line is different. I also don't use reserved variable names.

What could be causing this issue?

I want to render the following HTML

- EN: "Hello, {{vmApp.principal}}"
- IT: "Ciao, {{vmApp.principal}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the syntax error specifically, its not a valid syntax.  Tomcat will fail in a similar way.  This is because the unescaped use of brackets {} within other open brackets is treated as nested "eval-expressions" and isn't supported by the standard, i.e. see the spec for EL 3.0 section 1.2.1.